# How can I create a type synonym for Func<> delegate types in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Suppose I have code similar to this:

```
Func<int, int, int> combineResults(Func<int, int, int> f, Func<int, int, int> g)
{
    return (x, y) => f(x, y) + g(x, y);
}
```

I would like to make it more general and less verbose, presumably by way of type synonyms.  I know that I can create an type name using a delegate:

```
delegate int BinaryOp(int x, int y);
```

Or more generically as:

```
delegate int BinaryOp<T>(T x, T y);
```

However, this doesn't have a generic return type.  Must you always specify a return type in delegate declarations?  It seems so, from what I gather from the specification.
Is there a way to write something similar to "type" in C#:

```
type BinaryOp<T> = Func<T, T, T>
type BinaryCombinator<T> = Func<BinaryOp<T>, BinaryOp<T>, BinaryOp<T>>
BinaryCombinator<int> combineResults(f, g) { return (x, y) => f(x, y) + g(x, y) }
```

**EDIT (solution/future reference)**

As hvr and Anders pointed out, you *can* use a type variable for the return type in a delegate declaration, so an example of what I wanted can be written as follows:

```
delegate T BinaryOp<T>(T x, T y);
delegate BinaryOp<T> BinaryCombinator<T>(BinaryOp<T> f, BinaryOp<T> g);
static BinaryOp<int> sum = (x, y) => x + y;
static BinaryOp<int> sub = (x, y) => x - y;
static BinaryCombinator<int> combineResult = (f, g) => (x, y) => f(x, y) + g(x, y);
```

Which can be called in the following fashion:

```
combineResult(sum, sub)(2, 3);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `delegate T BinaryOp<T>(T x, T y);`?

Comment: @hvd Nothing, that's perfect.  In my haste I assumed that wasn't possible, as noted in the question.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Func<T, TResult>()` is just a standard delegate declaration, added to C# when generics where introduced to avoid having to declare your own delegate types all the time. The declaration of `Func<T, TResult>()` is

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg)
```

You can of course declare your own delegate in the same way as @hvd proposes:

```
public delegate T BinaryOp<T>(T x, Ty);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Must you always specify a return type in delegate declarations

Not at all - you don't even need a return type at all - look at `EventHandler<T>`:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(
    Object sender,
    TEventArgs e
)
```

> Is there a way to write something similar to "type" in C#

There's no `typedef` equivalent if that's what you're looking for.